# how to connect one class to another for an online shopping system?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am trying to create a admin function for an online shopping mall system which would allow the admin to manage the manager profile.

```
 package onlineshopping;

    /**
     *
     * @author mammo
     */
    public class Admin {

        private String adminName;

        public Admin(String adminName) {
            this.adminName = adminName;
        }

        public String getAdminName() {
            return adminName;
        }

        public void setAdminName(String adminName) {
            this.adminName = adminName;
        }




    }
     public String srhMgr(char mgrid, String mgrname)
        {
          public class Admin extends public class 
    { 
        private String mgrName = "";

          }
    }
```

However, I seem to have trouble with the connecting it with the Search Manager (srhMgr) function. is it the method I am using which is incorrect.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with the given code. Why do you think this is supposed to work?

Comment: well what are the issues in the programming? Can you give the details?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information or details of how you want to implement the Search Manager (srhMgr) function, a naive implementation using an array of `Admin` objects may help illustrate one way of connecting the `Admin` class to your `srhMgr` function.

```
package onlineshopping;

class Admin {
    private String adminName;
    private char mgrid;

    public Admin(String adminName, char mgrid) {
        this.adminName = adminName;
        this.mgrid = mgrid;
    }

    public String getAdminName() {
        return adminName;
    }

    public void setAdminName(String adminName) {
        this.adminName = adminName;
    }

    public char getMgrId() {
        return this.mgrid;
    }

}

public class AdminTest{
    public static Admin[] managers;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Admin boss = new Admin("Carl Cracker", 'a');

        managers = new Admin[3];

        // fill the managers array with Admin objects
        managers[0] = boss;
        managers[1] = new Admin("Harry Hacker", 'b');
        managers[2] = new Admin("Tommy Tester", 'c');

        String srh1 = srhMgr('x', "Cautious Clay");
        System.out.println(srh1);

        String srh2 = srhMgr('a', "Carl Cracker");
        System.out.println(srh2);
    }

    public static String srhMgr(char mgrid, String mgrname)
    {
        String SearchResult = "";

        for (Admin a : managers){
            if ((a.getMgrId() == mgrid) && a.getAdminName().equals(mgrname)) {
                SearchResult = a.getAdminName() + " IS FOUND in Search";
                break;
            }
            else{
                SearchResult = mgrname + " NOT found in search";
            }
        }
        return SearchResult;
    }
}
```

output:

```
Cautious Clay NOT found in search
Carl Cracker IS FOUND in Search
```

Many other, and better ways to do this, but this hopefully may help you moving forward.